# Compiler Deciding Ambiguous Parameter

Tags: c++, overriding

Pure curiousity, how does the compiler decide what type should go for an ambigious method (based off of param size).

In the example below that I have tested, we have method(int i) and method(char c). I tested calling method('C') and method(67) and the char and int method were called respectively. But 'C' is just ascii for 67. How does it decide since 67 also fits as a char (I could understand calling the int method if we called method(60000))
Is there a precedence or just parses it as char because it reads the quotes to help it decide. Similarly would we have ambiguity for an int and long method overrides?

```
void method(int i) {
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
void method(char c) {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    method('C'); // outputs char
    method(67); // outputs int
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Literals have types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Literals also have types** (like everything in C++, a statically-typed language).

A number in code has a type `int`, unless it is suffixed with [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) (or it doesn't fit into an `int`, it will be of the lowest signed type it would fit into, possible even of non-standard type `__int128`)

```
5 //int
5u //unsigned int
5ll //long long
```

A number with dot will be interpreted as double

```
5. // double
5.f // float
```

etc. You can find more exhaustive lists at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Literals).

An expression withing single quotes is interpreted as `char`, and within double quotes as null-terminated `const char[]` (with the length matching the length of the string + null terminator).

```
'a' // char
"abc" // const char[4]
```

Because of that, your code has no ambiguity. It's true that `char` is also an integer type, but it doesn't matter. Types for literals are clear and compiler can differentiate them in any situation.

Comment: Great answer, very thorough. I had forgotten that literals have types which @Jesper Juhl's answer provided. Not sure who to give it to, yours is more complete but his was sufficient to remind me about literal types. :D

Comment: Some minor nitpicking: 1. `"abc"` is `const char [4]`. 2. Integer literals can get larger types if their values don't fit into the default types.

Answer (score 1):

"how does the compiler decide what type should go for an ambigious method " - It *doesn't*. If something is ambiguous it's a compile time error. The compiler does not choose one thing over another in that case, it simply refuses to compile your code.

Note that literals *have types*. And in your example, there is no ambiguity. `char` and `int` are different types.

Comment: "If something is ambiguous it's a compile time error." Really? It doesn't choose the "best match?" Are you saying that `method(true);` would be a compile time error?

Comment: Correct. Forgot that literals have types and aren't treated just as their values. Duh!

Comment: @scohe001 if something is ambiguous after following all the rules of promotion and disambiguation in the standard, then yes, it's a compile time error. You know very well what I *mean*. Being pedantic is fine, but here you are not helping by being so. I *know* the rules, but here the letter of the law wouldn't help OP.

Comment: @JesperJuhl While scohe001 may know what you mean, people who don't know C++ might not.  Remember, your answer is for everyone, not just subject matter experts.

Comment: If OP is defining the calls they're making as "ambiguous," then their understanding of the word is clearly different from yours, mine and the standard's. I was trying to cheekily suggest you make your answer less "ambiguous" by better defining the word in terms of the standard :p

Comment: (Also a good example of an *actually* ambiguous call, would be `method(3.14);`, which would be great to show the OP and explain why it is "ambiguous")

Comment: @scohe001 *""If something is ambiguous it's a compile time error." Really? It doesn't choose the "best match?""* I always thought 'ambiguous' means 'there is no single best match'.

Comment: @scohe001 Ambigious probably wasn't the best phrase, but I had forgotten that literals have types... which is where the confusion was. Once that was alleviated, his answer is pretty well understood I believe. :D